# spring + thymeleaf - redirect to edit page which take @ModelAttribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to redirect my request to edit page if status is failed from server response.
below code will give us more clarity. updated the variable name and id's due to protocol.

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("abc")
public class CredentialsController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/editCredentials", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
    public String editCredentials(
        @ModelAttribute(value = "credential") 
        Credentials credential, HttpServletRequest request, Model model
    ) throws Exception {}

    @RequestMapping(value = "/update/{abc}", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET}) 
    public ModelAndView update (
        @Valid Form cForm, BindingResult bindResult,@PathVariable String abc,HttpServletRequest request, Model model
    ) throws Exception {
        if(response.getMessageStatus().getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("fail")){
            model.addAttribute("response",response);
            //TODO: redirect to edit page
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/app/editcredentials");
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="carrier" id="carrierId" action="#" th:action="@{/app/update/} + ${abc}" th:object="${cForm}" method="post">
    <div class="column-60" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; float: none;">
        <p class="form-header">Edit Form - <span th:text = ${Name}></span>
        .....
        .....
        <input type="submit" id="subBtn" class="button-orange" value="Save">
</form>
```

Above code is not redirecting to edit page, I tried returning the String in Controller "editcredentials" but not loading the page.
**Note:** I am in edit page and saving the data, if response from server is fail, I have to popup the response message and stay on the edit(same) page.
If we have any solution using Jquery and Javascript will also work.
I also searched how to redirect to GET to POST and tried but no luck.
Thank you

Comment: I tried using jquery: `event.preventDefault(); 

           var req = $.ajax({
               url: getContextPath()
       + "/app/update/{abc}",
               type: 'POST',
               data:  getFormData($(
       "form[name='carrierCreds']").serializeArray())
           });
        req.done(function(data) {
         console.log(data);
        });
     form.submit();` before submit but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you friends.
I am using .dialog() function.
If ajax call is fail we open a dialog with message and using close function so it will stay on same page.